# Can't add 10.04 computer to UbuntuOne

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one

No matter what I try clicking on UbuntuOne within System>Preferences, it will NOT trigger my browser to open a webpage that allows me to add this computer. Please help. I have already gone thru the instructions for completely removing and reinstalling UbuntuOne. I have checked the Passwords and Encryption Keys program and there is NO entry for https://ubuntuone.com yadda yadda yadda. This is driving me nuts!!

I am trying to convert over to UbuntuOne from DropBox but if I can't even add this 10.04 computer I can't use UbuntuOne.

Answer (score 1):

This should work ok without any problems it is an LTS.

If you [Contact Support](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/) they should be able to help.

Comment: That's about all you can do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Register to it in programm or in website www.one.ubuntu.com
2. In programm Click Devices and there click Connect. Thats whats left. I know ive experienced also why not auto starts. But maybe not always u want to immediately start syncing so they left to not auto connect.